# GoPro Hero 5 Session camera for long shot (crowd shot)

Tags: video, video-recording, camera, 4k

I am asked to shoot noncommercial event, which will last several days. I have my usual camera for close and middle shots (Lumix G6), and I am thinking to by cheap 4K camera for long shots (crowd shots) and cut peaces of them after.

I heard that [GoPro Hero 5 Session](http://shop.gopro.com/cameras/hero5-session/CHDHS-501.html) are capable of recording in 4K, but will it be helpful in this case? Or maybe there is better solution quality/price for long shot?

Comment: When you say "will it be helpful" what exactly are you asking? You might get better answers by being more specific.

Comment: To be more specific, it's requires to have more experience in this topic. If I had an experience in this specific topic, then the question would not be needed. I don't know about any pitfalls (underwater rocks), so asked help from more experienced people.

Comment: That depends on what you want to use the footage for, what's the end medium, what's the expectation on the footage and what the client asked for. More information is needed, to answer this question

Answer (score 2):

Yes, useful for wide crowd shots.
Yes, you can crop down/scale up 1080p selections from the 4K to simulate additional camera angles.

Consider using the gopro app or a wifi remote to stop/start the gopro so you don't have to physically access the device while monitoring your main camera(s).

Not sure how long the event will run for but you might want to look at an external USB power source too.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever camera you go with, keep in mind that 4K sensors run hot. I would run tests, under above normal room temps, you will likely want to run a small fan over the camera, overheating will shut it down.

But a camera like the HERO 5 would be fine, tethered to a computer with a HDD that can continuously record... just keep it cool.